# Eureka; cannot pass request through eureka server by restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Please help to solve the problem, I cannot make a request to the second application through the eureka service.

Here is my code:

EurekaServer:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

---

---

Application client:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ClientFirstApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(ClientFirstApplication.class, args);
   }

   @Bean
   @LoadBalanced
   public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(){
      return new RestTemplate();
   }

}
```

```
@RestController
public class ClientFirstController {

     @Autowired
   public RestTemplate restTemplate;

   @GetMapping("/connect-server")
   public String serverFirstConnect(){
      return restTemplate.getForObject("http://server/home-server", String.class);
   }

}
```

```
server.port=8080

spring.application.name=client
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

---

---

Application Client2:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ServerFirstApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(ServerFirstApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

```
@RestController
public class ServerFirstController {
   @GetMapping("/home-server")
   public String home(){
      return "<h1> This is Home page for Server First</h1>";
   }
}
```

```
server.port=8081

spring.application.name=server
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

---

---

when I go to the link http://localhost:8080/connect-server, there is always an error

---

---

```
2022-11-03 06:46:34.241 ERROR 8256 --- [o-auto-1-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://server/home-server": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:532) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:637) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:280) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:385) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:407) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.BlockingLoadBalancerRequest.apply(BlockingLoadBalancerRequest.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.BlockingLoadBalancerRequest.apply(BlockingLoadBalancerRequest.java:32) ~[spring-cloud-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerRequestAdapter.apply(LoadBalancerRequestAdapter.java:43) ~[spring-cloud-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.blocking.client.BlockingLoadBalancerClient.execute(BlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:114) ~[spring-cloud-loadbalancer-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.blocking.client.BlockingLoadBalancerClient.execute(BlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:91) ~[spring-cloud-loadbalancer-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:334) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at com.mykola.client_first.controllers.ClientFirstController.serverFirstConnect(ClientFirstController.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2022-11-03 06:50:21.655  INFO 8256 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2022-11-03 06:55:21.657  INFO 8256 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
```

disabling the load balancer gives another error, as in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vS193hfwbdI&t=42s

Answer (score 1):

You should use `EurekaClient` to discover service instances from the Eureka Server as described in [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html#_using_the_eurekaclient).

Try to define your controller in the way shown below.

```java
@RestController
public class ClientFirstController {

   @Autowired
   public RestTemplate restTemplate;

   @Autowired
   private EurekaClient eurekaClient;

   @GetMapping("/connect-server")
   public String serverFirstConnect(){
      String serverId = "server";
      String homePageUrl = eurekaClient.getNextServerFromEureka(serverId, false).getHomePageUrl();
      return restTemplate.getForObject(homePageUrl+"home-server", String.class);
   }
}
```